# Redirect/remove a querystring in hapijs with a prehandler

Tags: node.js, redirect, hapi

In hapijs I need to remove a querystring from a URL if it appears using a prehandler.

For example this URL:
    https://www.example.com/products/speakers/psb-ps1-232344/?prodSource=speaker%20line%20products

Should redirect to this:
https://www.example.com/products/speakers/psb-ps1-232344/

Where I have /products/{brand}/{productName}-{productId}/

Comment: May be check it out - https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing a simple split and destructure.

```
const [url] = "https://www.example.com/products/speakers/psb-ps1-232344/?prodSource=speaker%20line%20products".split("?")
console.log(url)
```

Comment: I actually did it like this: `if (request.path && request.query.prodSource) {
    var targetUrl = request.path;
    return reply.redirect(targetUrl).permanent(true);  }`